# How do I include the wordpress title in the URL while echo in conditional tag?

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile, echo

Below is the code for displaying WhatsApp sharing icon, condition used `wp_is_mobile`:

```
<?php
  if (wp_is_mobile()) {
  echo '<a href="whatsapp://send?text=' . the_title() . ', from ' . get_bloginfo('name') . '   ' . wp_get_shortlink() . '" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">';
  echo '<i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i></a>';
}
 ?>
```

The `the_title` is showing the Post title on the screen before WhatsApp icon, instead in the URL.
How do I make the post title is part of the URL and not showing in the text on screen

Comment: Did you try with `get_the_title()`?

Comment: Yes, as @dingo_d advised below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/), but besides that I'd [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the whole thing:

```
<?php
    if (wp_is_mobile()) {
        echo '<a href="whatsapp://send?text=' . urlencode(get_the_title() . ', from ' . get_bloginfo('name') . '   ' . wp_get_shortlink()) . '" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">';
        echo '<i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i></a>';
    }
?>
```

As described [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title):

> (the_title()) Displays or returns the title of the current post. This tag may only be used within The Loop, to get the title of a post outside of the loop use get_the_title. If the post is protected or private, this will be noted by the words "Protected: " or "Private: " prepended to the title.

Comment: Glad I could help :)